# Hide Cancel/Auto And Capture button from VNDocumentCameraViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, visionkit, vndocumentcameraviewcontroller

I have set up `VNDocumentCameraViewController` for scanning documents automatically. I want to hide the cancel and capture buttons from the screen. Is it possible to hide these buttons?

Code:-

```
import UIKit
import Vision
import VisionKit
import AVFoundation

class DocumentScannerViewController: UIViewController, VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate {

var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let scannerViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
    scannerViewController.delegate = self
    present(scannerViewController, animated: true)
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: AVCaptureSession())
    previewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    previewLayer?.frame = view.bounds
    previewLayer?.cornerRadius = 10
    previewLayer?.opacity = 0.75
    previewLayer?.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    previewLayer?.borderWidth = 5.0
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
}

func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
    for pageNumber in 0..<scan.pageCount {
        let image = scan.imageOfPage(at: pageNumber)
        if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
            print(imageData)
        }
        if let cgImage = image.cgImage {
            print("cgImage", cgImage)
        }
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
}

func documentCameraViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
}

func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
   }
}
```

Please refer to the attached screenshot for clarification.

[image: ScreenShot]

My question is, how can I hide these buttons? I've tried the above code, but haven't achieved any results yet.